# Toolbar as sub navigation bar in NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm building an iOS app using a `NavigationController`. However, in this app I need a sub navigation bar and it needs to be in every view. I initially implemented this using a toolbar in every view. But what happens, when a new view slides in, is that the toolbar slides in as well. I need the toolbar to be persistent, like the navigation bar. What's the best way to approach this?

My best guess is to set `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];` to `YES` and then somehow positioning that underneath the navbar...

This is how I used to do it in every viewcontroller:

```
@interface TableViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *mainToolBar;

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"TV Shows";
    [self addRightMenuButton];

    [self loadNinjas];

    self.mainToolBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.mainToolBar.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    self.mainToolBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
    self.mainToolBar.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
    self.mainToolBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;

    self.tableView.dataSource=self;
    self.tableView.delegate=self;
}
```

Comment: See Apple's take on it - [ExtendedNavBarViewController.m](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Listings/ExtendedNavBar_ExtendedNavBarViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007418-ExtendedNavBar_ExtendedNavBarViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_18)

Answer (score 0):

Three distinct approaches I can think of trying:

- Make a taller Navigation Bar subclass with your secondary toolbar thing at the bottom. Set it as the Navigation Controller's Navigation Bar. I've tried this a couple of times to achieve different things and it didn't work out, but maybe it will for you.
- Stick with what you're doing, a second toolbar on every VC, and use a custom VC transition or presentation controller to make it appear like the toolbar isn't moving while the rest of the content is.
- Don't do this. I can't really see a way that a double navigation thing is going to be good for an iPhone app.